# JS - JSON/ARRAY pass variable in Constructor (custom library)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, constructor

If i follow the documentation, the right way to setup the data entry is:

```
$("#container").flipBook({    

css:"css/style.css",
pages:[  
    {
       src:"images/book1/page1.jpg",
       thumb:"images/book1/thumb1.jpg",
       title:"Cover",
       htmlContent:''
    },
    {
       src:"images/book1/page2.jpg",
       thumb:"images/book1/thumb2.jpg",
       title:"Page two"
    }, 
    etc.. etc..
  ],
  btnNext:true,
  btnPrev:true,
  btnZoomIn:true,
  btnZoomOut:true,
  other parameters...
```

So, I'd like to insert data dynamically. 
I declare a new Array, than i scroll all pages from a xml file, I create an object and in the end i push the object inside the first array declared.
var page = new Array();

```
var created=0;

bla bla bla

$(xml).find('page').each(function(i){

    var singlepage = new Object();                                      
    singlepage.src ="image1.jpg";
    singlepage.thumb="thum1.jpg";
    created++;
    singlepage.title="Page "+created;
    page.push(JSON.stringify(singlepage));
});


var book = {};

book["book-"+id] = $("#tabs-" + id + "").flipBook({

    pages: ????????,
    btnNext:true,
    etc.. etc..
```

I tried to put `page`, `[page]`, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(page))`. I don't know how could I pass the variable inside the constructor.

It seems a very simple problem, but i don't find any solution.
Help me, please :)

Comment: Change `page.push(JSON.stringify(singlepage));` to `page.push(singlepage);` and `pages: page,` should work fine. `JSON.stringify` converts an object to a **string**. You want an object though, so don't convert it.

Comment: Apparently, from what I see, the expected output of the `pages` property is an **array of objects**, hence just remove `JSON.stringify` and set `pages: page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
var pages = [];
$(xml).find('page').each(function(i) {
  var singlepage = {
    src: "image1.jpg",
    thumb: "thum1.jpg",
    title: "Page " + ++created;
  };
  pages.push(singlepage);
});
```

and you can just pass the `pages` object:

```
 $("#tabs-" + id + "").flipBook({
   pages: pages
   // ...
 });
```

Comment: The main difference: page.push(JSON.stringify(singlepage)); -> pages.push(singlepage); right? :)

Comment: @FabioSorre: Exactly, because you need an array of objects, while stringify will convert an object to a JSON String, which is not needed here.

Comment: @FabioSorre: I recommend to [read about what `JSON.stringify` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). (always read the documentation before using an unfamiliar function!)

Comment: @FabioSorre : It's totally okay, the question was okay and the format was fine, so just don't forget to check what that method does because you probably will need that someday, it's always good to know the difference between an array, an object and a json string ;) Also, don't forget to accept andrusieczko's answer if your problem is solved!

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for suggestion, I know what stringify does ;) I used it cuz before that i needed it